# unable to merge variables with array_merge: undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to combine two variables that retrieves information from MySQL.

I have been suggested to use `array_merge()`, and it seems to work for the most part. I keep getting `Warning: Illegal string offset` after all the results has been returned from the database. Interesting is that the first 8 (the query has a LIMIT of 8) are error clean, after the 8 results has been printed, then a huge list appears with that error.

### query

`articleClass.php`

```
public function latestArticles()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles       
                               WHERE article_uid = article_uid
                               ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT 8");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}

public function articleTags()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT a.*, b.*
                               FROM articles a, article_tags b
                               WHERE b.tag_id = a.article_uid
                               ");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}
```

### printing code

`index.php`

```
include 'libraries/articleClass/articleClass.php';

$articleClass       = new articleClass();
$latestArticles     = $articleClass->latestArticles();
    $articleTags        = $articleClass->articleTags();

foreach(array_merge($latestArticles, $articleTags) as $data)
{   
$first_uid      = $data['article_uid'];
$first_image    = $data['article_image'];
$first_title    = $data['article_title'];
$first_content  = $data['article_content'];
$first_created  = gmdate("d M Y", $data['article_created']);
$first_tags     = $data['tag_name'];

echo '
    <article>
        <img src="path-to-image/'.$first_image.'"/>
        <h1>'.$first_title.'</h1>
        <p>'.$first_content.'</p>
            <ul>
                <li>'.$first_tags.'</li>
            </ul>

    </article>
';
}
```

Once `index.php` is loaded, 8 articles are printed on the page as they should, but I get :

> Notice: Undefined index: tag_name in /var/www/new-design/index.php on line 74

### Trial & (mostly) Failures

If I change public function article_tags to `Fetch` instead of `FetchAll` I get these errors:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /var/www/new-design/index.php on line 67
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/new-design/index.php on line 67

I am unable to figure out how to succeed with this, any leads would be great. I've been at it since morning!

### UPDATE

article_tags table

```
+--------------------------------+
| tag_id | article_id | tag_name |
+--------------------------------+
|   1    |     8      | awesome  |
|   2    |     8      | sweet    |
|   3    |     8      | gross    |
+--------------------------------+
```

there is only one article_id corresponding to the articles that are being called, yet this article still receives undefined index: tag_name of course because in the array_merge they haven't been merged at all.

Comment: One of the causes could be the unquoted `WHERE article_uid = article_uid` --- can you try `WHERE article_uid = 'article_uid'` or `WHERE article_uid = '$article_uid'` see if that makes a difference with the quotes and/or the `$` sign, since you're using `$first_uid = $data['article_uid'];`

Comment: I don't think `array_merge` does what you want here: Assuming `$sth->db->fetchAll()` returns an array with numeric keys your resulting array is simply 1 array appended to the other. You might want to post the results of `print_r($latestArticles)` and `print_r($articleTags)` (shorten it if you need to so your post stays readable) so we can show you what the result actually is (and you can tell us what it should be).

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for the suggestion but quotes has no effect on the outcome of it as long as they're assigned correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Glad to know it got resolved, cheers. @AttisBarros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that

```
array_merge($latestArticles, $articleTags)
```

simply appends one array to the other, meaning:
The first 8 entries in the resulting array are your articles (these have the "tag_name" field set).

The rest is filled with the contents of $articleTags (those don't have "tag_name" field - causing your error).

Here's some code to illustrate that (Indices 0 to 2 are your articles while 3 to 5 are your tags, notice how indices 3-5 of the resulting array don't have the tag_name field):

```
$latestArticles = array(
    array("article_title" => "Some Title 1", "tag_name" => "SomeTag"),
    array("article_title" => "Some Title 2", "tag_name" => "SomeOtherTag"),
    array("article_title" => "Some Title 3", "tag_name" => "SomeTag"),
);

$articleTags = array(
    array("name" => "SomeTag", "somefield" => "foo", "otherfield" => "bar"),
    array("name" => "SomeTagOtherTag", "somefield" => "baz", "otherfield" => "test"),
    array("name" => "YetAnotherTag", "somefield" => "test2", "otherfield" => "test3")
);


$result = array_merge($latestArticles, $articleTags);
print_r($result);

/** Resulting Array:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [article_title] => Some Title 1
            [tag_name] => SomeTag
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [article_title] => Some Title 2
            [tag_name] => SomeOtherTag
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [article_title] => Some Title 3
            [tag_name] => SomeTag
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeTag
            [somefield] => foo
            [otherfield] => bar
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeTagOtherTag
            [somefield] => baz
            [otherfield] => test
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => YetAnotherTag
            [somefield] => test2
            [otherfield] => test3
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the illustration, I was updating the question in response to your answer. As I had started, I will update it now. So as I mentioned in the update, even the article that has the tags doesn't have the tag_name as they aren't merging, although I was able to accomplish this before, yet I don't remember how but it was achieved with array_merge. | EDIT: I see what you are saying though, so array_merge won't serve me here, yet I haven't been able to find another way of accomplishing this..

Comment: If you simply want the to have your tag-information together with your article information you might want to alter your query `latestArticles()` to include the according tag information (similar to how you do it in `latestTags()`).

Comment: Sadly I tried, even with INNER JOIN it didn't seem to work as it gave multiple of the same results.

Comment: Does `article_uid` of the `article` table contain the id of the tag? (Your second function suggests that, though from a standard naming scheme I'd guess that's the user id of the person who posted the article). EDIT: You might simply just post (some, header would be enough) of your article table under the tag table to better show the connection between those two.

Comment: Yes, you may see it here. article_tags table http://i.imgur.com/L3waAJO.png and articles table http://i.imgur.com/SVDHFQX.png

Comment: Sadly, there are no column names in your second image (the one with the articles). This might work though if the field names are correct: `SELECT a.*, t.tag_name FROM articles a, article_tags t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_uid ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT 8`

Comment: Sorry, here it is with the column names. http://i.imgur.com/iJUfJS6.png EDIT: Believe it or not, I had already tried that. What it does is that it just prints three articles(article_id=116), so it ends up printing the same article the number of times it is in the article_tags table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44917/discussion-between-cckep-and-attis-barros)